# making a Javascript object inside another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make an object using `angular.forEach()` function and then I need to push another object and initialize all the values to false but the below way points errors.

How can do this correctly? if I use "item.id" and "index.id" it will not create the intended functionality. I am attaching a photo to point out the intended functionality.[link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up64z.jpg)

```
        angular.forEach(metaData.validationRules, function (item, key) {
            //want to push object to another object
            angular.forEach(insarray.instances, function (index, key) {
               $scope.select = {
                    item.id: {
                        index.id:false
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I believe the way your creating your object properties is wrong, you cannot use the string value of a variable as the property name in a literal. You should use the square bracket notation against an already created object. EDIT: Also be aware if you have two `item.id`'s with the same value the last will overwrite the others.

Comment: array.push() method doesnt apply here as this is an object

Comment: Well, you can no push object in another object. `Object` is a collection of key=>value. You should mention key which will hold value..

Comment: @ste2425 no all the ids are identical here.

Comment: You could use a pair of nested reduce's on your source arrays. However i really don't understand the point in this. Maybe some context? Here's an example of reduce. No need for Angular at all. Its not the nicest thing to look at. https://jsfiddle.net/Lnesc2Lz/

Answer (score 1):

It is not available for now but with ES6 you can also use this syntax.

```
angular.forEach(metaData.validationRules, function (item, key) {
  //want to push object to another object
  angular.forEach(insarray.instances, function (index, key) {
    $scope.select={
      [item.id]: {
        [index.id]:false
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[More example here](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it's not possible to set the key of a key-value-pair the way you do it in your example. A better approach would be:

```
$scope.select = {};
angular.forEach(metaData.validationRules, function (item, key) {
    $scope.select[item.id] = $scope.select[item.id] || {};

    angular.forEach(insarray.instances, function (index, key) {
        $scope.select[item.id][index.id] = false;
    });
});
```

Consider the declaration of the new select object outside of the loops. This is important, otherwise you would overwrite the object on each cycle.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined, where index.id is 3. You have to do this first: `$scope.select[item.id] = {}`

Comment: I'd recommend this: $scope.select[item.id] = $scope.select[item.id]  || {}

Comment: I tried using both second and first method.But still getting that error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined.Also i declared $scope.select ={}  outside the loop.

Comment: Reduce would get around the issue of creating empty objects if they do not exist. Also if `validationRules` and `instances` is an array just use `validationRule.forEach` its native. No need to make your code dependent on angular for no reason.